# What is the concept of making the program download then install the apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio

*What is the concept of making the program download then install the apk*
I have made the install program but when I made the install program it didn't work

```
        download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String getUrl = "https://apptrue.online/files/Truejek.apk";
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(getUrl));
                String title = URLUtil.guessFileName(getUrl, null, null);
                request.setTitle(title);
                request.setDescription("Sedang mendowload file");
                String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(getUrl);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookie);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title);

                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this, "Download dimulai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checkWriteExternalStoragePermission();
            }
        });

        install.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PackageInstaller.Session session = null;
                try {
                    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
                    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
                    int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
                    session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
                    addApkToInstallSession(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, session);
                    DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
                    dpm.clearDeviceOwnerApp(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                    checkWriteExternalStoragePermission();
                    Context context = UpdateActivity.this;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                    intent.setAction(PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    IntentSender statusReceiver = pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
                    // Commit the session (this will start the installation workflow).
                    session.commit(statusReceiver);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Tidak dapat menginstal paket", e);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    if (session != null) {
                        session.abandon();
                    }
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void addApkToInstallSession(String assetName, PackageInstaller.Session session)
            throws IOException {
        // It's recommended to pass the file size to openWrite(). Otherwise installation may fail
        // if the disk is almost full.
        try (OutputStream packageInSession = session.openWrite("package", 0, -1);
             InputStream is = getAssets().open(assetName)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1638400];
            int n;
            while ((n = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                packageInSession.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        }
    }
    // Note: this Activity must run in singleTop launchMode for it to be able to receive the intent
    // in onNewIntent().
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            int status = extras.getInt(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS);
            String message = extras.getString(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS_MESSAGE);
            switch (status) {
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION:
                    // This test app isn't privileged, so the user has to confirm the install.
                    Intent confirmIntent = (Intent) extras.get(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT);
                    startActivity(confirmIntent);
                    break;
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_SUCCESS:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Berhasil di install!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE:
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_ABORTED:
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_BLOCKED:
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT:
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_INCOMPATIBLE:
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_INVALID:
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_STORAGE:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Install gagal! " + status + ", " + message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Status tidak dikenal diterima dari penginstal: " + status,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


        private void checkWriteExternalStoragePermission () {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(UpdateActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                //  If we don't have permission than requesting  the permission
                requestWriteExternalStoragePermission();
            }
        }

        private void requestWriteExternalStoragePermission () {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(UpdateActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UpdateActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UpdateActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult ( int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults){
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE && grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this, "Izin Tidak Diberikan.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

**It doesn't work on android 12 and 13**
then where is the error for using the installer package

```
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
                    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
                    int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
                    session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
                    addApkToInstallSession(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, session);
                    DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
                    dpm.clearDeviceOwnerApp(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                    checkWriteExternalStoragePermission();
                    Context context = UpdateActivity.this;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                    intent.setAction(PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    IntentSender statusReceiver = pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
                    // Commit the session (this will start the installation workflow).
                    session.commit(statusReceiver);
```

I started deploying the app via a local webiste link not using the google play console to distribute it, so I want to create my own installer concept

Comment: did my solution fit your requirements @AlbarDev?

Answer (score 0):

You might get it done with a single line (with the help of [AndroidUtilCode](https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode))

```
AppUtils.installApp(apkFile)
```

where `apkFile` is a `File` object of the apk you want to install/update. This will prompt the installation dialog to the user.

Remember to include the permission to install packages in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

This is a `protection level: normal` permission, meaning it doesn't require the user to grant it through the runtime permissions, but yet the user has to enable the option in the settings of the app that is thought to install packages.

I have not tried this yet in Android 12 and 13 but it should work and save you lots of lines